# Unable to bind LINQ to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, data-binding, gridview

I just using a simple LINQ query having group by clause and trying to bind its result set to GridView.
My LINQ query looks like

```
var expData = from c in WebDB.TransTable
              group c by c.enterdate into g
              select g;
```

Grid view on ASP.NET page

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="true" runat="server" DataKeyField="Key" />
```

But getting the error:

> A field or property with the name 'Key' was not found on the selected data source.

Anyone can help me please?

None of the answers were helpful

Comment: You'll need to remove the `"`s from your linq statement - it's treating it as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** This ignores the "" in your linq statement

Look at the attribute on your asp.net GridView(aspx code): DataKeyField="" is pointing to a column name that does not exist in your linq query

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="true" DataKeyField="Key"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

`expData` is a `string` as you've put the LINQ query inside quotation marks.

```
var expData = "from c in WebDB.TransTable
            group c by c.enterdate into g
              select g;"
```

`System.String` does not have a property called `Key`, hence the error.

If you remove the quotation marks it should all work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had your problem either , I wrote like this . I hope this work for you  :

```
var expData = from c in WebDB.TransTable
              group c by c.enterdate into g
              select new {EnterDate = g.Key};
```