# Unable to bind LINQ to gridview

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to bind LINQ to gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028881/unable-to-bind-linq-to-gridview)

I'm just using a simple LINQ query having group by clause and trying to bind its result set to GridView. My LINQ query looks like

```
var expData = from c in WebDB.TblTrans
              group c by c.transdate into g
              select g;
```

Grid view on ASP.NET page

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="true" runat="server" DataKeyField="Key" />
```

But getting the error:

> A field or property with the name 'Key' was not found on the selected data source.

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: Kind of, he did remove the quotes from the query at least!

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty explicit, either get rid of the `DataKeyField` from your gridview code or you need to query against something that has a column named `Key`

Disregard the above, it seems I didn't notice your group statement. But I would still try binding to the gridview without the data key field to make sure your query is running appropriately

Comment: The result of the query is an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>`. [`IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx) **has** a property `Key`.

Comment: Good point, didn't notice the group statement